# Wrote Same Variable For Multiple Events With Bind Value Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

Let say we have 2 variable that use in multiple events.

But each variable take value from event itself.

For example

```
$('#el1').click(function() {
    var a = $('#inp').val(); //same as a below event
    var b = $(this).attr('for'); //same as b below event
    data = { c1 : a, c2 : b };
});

$('#el2').click(function() {
    var a = $('#inp').val(); // same as a above event
    var b = $(this).attr('for'); // same as b above event
    data = { f1 : a, f2 : b };
});
```

In above code that wrote same variable for some events.
Each variable has same element attribute but also
will bind different value, cause the variable put into different event.

You know we only need wrote same variable at once.
without make same variable twice in it events.

Then how to do..?

Comment: Your main problem (trivial but...) in simplifying your code is that you use different properties  in yout `data` object literals - depending on the clicked button(?)

Comment: `data` not in case. Problem is in `a` and `b` without writing that twice in each events.

Comment: Sorry I have really difficulties (due to your English) to clearly understand your request: You want to wrote the above code only once without copy-pasting it all over the place? I mean... what's your issue currently?

Comment: The only problem you have above is that you use different `data = { c1 : a, c2 : b }` properties! (c1,c2), and for the other button you have `f1,f2` properties, and I don't know where you're getting that `c` and `f` from.

Comment: The code is just example not in practice. The case is on how to make `a` and `b` variable to wrote only at once. Because has a same attribute. Instead of make `a` and `b` for each events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you need to use global variables.  [This](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) explains the rules for javascript variable scope.

Generally, global variables should be used sparingly, to avoid getting them mixed up throughout your code.  Also, there are problems with what you want to do.

Let's look at `b` first.  You are thinking that they are the "same variable."  But they aren't: `this` refers to `el1` in your first event, and it refers to `el2` in your second event.  So, just because you are defining them with the same code, they are not going to be the same value.  You need to keep them separate.

Now, suppose you do create a global variable for `a`, like this:

```
var a = $('#inp').val(); 

$('#el1').click(function() {
    var b = $(this).attr('for'); 
    data = { c1 : a, c2 : b };
});

$('#el2').click(function() {
    var b = $(this).attr('for'); // same as b above event
    data = { f1 : a, f2 : b };
});
```

When you do this, `a` will equal the value of your `inp` element *at the point in time that you declare the variable.*  That value will have changed by the time that you fire your `click` event, so you will have an error that will be very hard to find if you don't understand this.

If you really want to, you can do a global variable like this:

```
var a = $('#inp');
```

and then in your handler:

```
data = { c1 : a.val(), c2 : b }
```

This will work because the reference to your `inp` element will remain the same as long as the page runs.  But `val()` will change, so you can't include it.

While it does save some processor work to avoid getting the element multiple times by storing a reference to it in a variable, you have to balance that against adding complications to your code.  Development overhead can be a lot more expensive than performance overhead.  (If that weren't true, nobody would be using jQuery, since plain old javascript runs faster and takes up less space.)  For this reason, I don't recommend that you do this.  The only reason that it makes sense to use your `a` and `b` variables at all is that it makes the line that assigns your `data` variable easier to read.  As such, it's best to leave them as they are.

The best time to store a property of a DOM element to a variable is if you are referencing it in a loop, and it doesn't change while you're in that loop.  In that case I would say that it's best practice to do so.